# Google craws errors of links that don't, and Never existed

Tags: redirect, seo, google-analytics, 404-page, link

In the last couple of days I'm having trouble with Googlebot crawlers.

I've experienced an increased of 404 links that don't exist, and have never existed.

Trying to see the origin of these 404 links is not possible so I really don't understand what's going on. The only thing that I can see is this:

**Last crawled:** 6/23/15

**First detected:** 6/23/15

*Googlebot couldn't crawl this URL because it points to a non-existent page. Generally, 404s don't harm your site's performance in search, but you can use them to help improve the user experience.* "

I don't have relative URL´s. All my URLs are absolute.

There are links that I already redirect to the correct one in the htaccess like this:

"Redirect 301 /en/wine/shipping-returns.html http://helloworld.com/en/shipping-returns.html"

The URL /en/wine/shipping-returns.html that was detected NEVER exist.

The thing is that the category wine was created. The problem is that the category as nothing to do with the page shipping-return.html. 
The shipping-return.html is a CMS page and the category wine is a category of products.

The two together doesn´t make any sense. And would never had been together.

If I tried to see the origin of the tracking error it notifies me that it was on a specific page. But when I try to find out in the HTML code where the link is...it doesn´t exist. The only thing that exist is a link:

```
<a title="Shipping and Returns" href="http://helloworld.com/en/shipping-returns.html"> Shipping and Returns</a>
```

and another link:

```
<a title=" Wines" href="http://helloworld.com/en/wine.html">Wine</a>
```

So this is very frustating.

Can anyone help me?

Thank You

Comment: I would guess you have a link to shipping-returns.html on the wine page instead of /shipping-returns.html

Comment: Sorry Douglas,

I forgot to put the code.
As you can see the link is correct so I really don´t understand the problem.

Thank you